# Wordpress emails are going to spam

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I am using WP Mail SMTP plugin.

```
function set_my_mail_content_type() {
    return "text/html";
}

function send_smtp_email( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host       = WPMS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = WPMS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port       = WPMS_SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->Username   = WPMS_SMTP_USER;
    $phpmailer->Password   = WPMS_SMTP_PASS;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WPMS_SSL;
    $phpmailer->From       = WPMS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName   = WPMS_SMTP_USER;
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'renderHTML' );

 function renderHTML(){
    $to = "nvillarejoupwork@gmail.com"; //sendto@example.com
    $subject = 'The subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','set_my_mail_content_type' );
    add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}

function send_smtp_email( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host       = WPMS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = WPMS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port       = WPMS_SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->Username   = WPMS_SMTP_USER;
    $phpmailer->Password   = WPMS_SMTP_PASS;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WPMS_SSL;
    $phpmailer->From       = WPMS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName   = WPMS_SMTP_USER;
}
```

There are my codes above. It is sending emails but they are going to spam folder.
I am not sure why.
Could you possibly help me?

Answer (score 0):

Generic content like that will always be spam-filtered by bigger mail providers. You can either whitelist the email address in Gmail or try a real name and a real message.

Another issue could be that the there are no MX records for the email (FROM) and the IP address of your server. If that's the case, you might need to use a SMTP plugin.